# Why can't create the #Articole table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I try to create one tenp table (#Articole) but without succes. Where is the mistake?

```
Declare @Articol int,
       @Sql NVarchar(max)
set @Articol = 99190
set @Sql=N'
select im.ItemName, im.ItemCode, d.ItemId as PromoId, im.Enabled, im.ItemId, dfv.DiscountFilterValueId
into #Articol
from Discount d (nolock) 
join DiscountFilter df (nolock) on df.DiscountId = d.ItemId
Join DiscountFilterValue dfv (nolock) on dfv.DiscountFilterId = df.DiscountFilterId
join Item i (nolock) on d.ItemId = i.ItemId
Join Item im (nolock) on im.ItemId = dfv.TextValue
where df.EntityId = 184'

IF @Articol <> -1 set @Sql = @Sql + ' and im.ItemId = @Articol'
If @Articol = -1 set @Sql = @Sql
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Articol int', @Articol

select * from #Articole
```

Comment: You *can* create it.  But it is a temporary table and out of scope after the dynamic query exits.

Comment: You are creating it, however, a temporary table only persists for the duration of the connection that made it. As the statement is being run within `sp_executesql` the table is dropped as soon as that finishes. If you want to reference the table afterwards, you'll need to create it before the dynamic batch.

Comment: I do not think you need dynamic sql here at all. This will suffice in your where clause: `and (@articol = -1 or im.ItemId = @articol)`.

Comment: Error message : (4 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 53
Invalid object name '##Articole'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Articole (ItemName NVARCHAR(MAX), ItemCode INT, ItemId INT, Enabled BIT, SecondItemId INT, DiscountFilterValueId INT)
    SET @Sql=N'
    insert into #Articol
    select im.ItemName, im.ItemCode, d.ItemId as PromoId, im.Enabled, im.ItemId, dfv.DiscountFilterValueId      
    from Discount d (nolock) 
    join DiscountFilter df (nolock) on df.DiscountId = d.ItemId
    Join DiscountFilterValue dfv (nolock) on dfv.DiscountFilterId = df.DiscountFilterId
    join Item i (nolock) on d.ItemId = i.ItemId
    Join Item im (nolock) on im.ItemId = dfv.TextValue
    where df.EntityId = 184'

    IF @Articol <> -1 set @Sql = @Sql + ' and im.ItemId = @Articol'
    If @Articol = -1 set @Sql = @Sql
    exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Articol int', @Articol

    select * from #Articole
```

I didn't know your columns type, I just guess it. Make sure types are proper

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me about mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** You do not need dynamic sql here at all. This will suffice in your original query: `and (@articol = -1 or im.ItemId = @articol)`.

A temporary table is limited to the scope which created it. You either need to create it before `sp_executesql`, or move rest of your statements inside the dynamic query string itself, or make it a global temporary table by prefixing with `##` instead of a single `#`.

Since I do not know the schema of the tables in actual query, below is a trick to create it beforehand.

```
select top 0 im.ItemName, im.ItemCode, d.ItemId as PromoId, im.Enabled, im.ItemId, dfv.DiscountFilterValueId
into #Articol
from Discount d (nolock) 
join DiscountFilter df (nolock) on df.DiscountId = d.ItemId
Join DiscountFilterValue dfv (nolock) on dfv.DiscountFilterId = df.DiscountFilterId
join Item i (nolock) on d.ItemId = i.ItemId
Join Item im (nolock) on im.ItemId = dfv.TextValue
where df.EntityId = 184

@Sql NVarchar(max)
set @Articol = 99190
set @Sql=N'
insert into #Articol
select im.ItemName, im.ItemCode, d.ItemId as PromoId, im.Enabled, im.ItemId, dfv.DiscountFilterValueId
from Discount d (nolock) 
join DiscountFilter df (nolock) on df.DiscountId = d.ItemId
Join DiscountFilterValue dfv (nolock) on dfv.DiscountFilterId = df.DiscountFilterId
join Item i (nolock) on d.ItemId = i.ItemId
Join Item im (nolock) on im.ItemId = dfv.TextValue
where df.EntityId = 184'

IF @Articol <> -1 set @Sql = @Sql + ' and im.ItemId = @Articol'
If @Articol = -1 set @Sql = @Sql
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Articol int', @Articol

select * from #Articole
```

Comment: "EDIT You do not need dynamic sql here at all. This will suffice in your original query: ```and (@articol = -1 or im.ItemId = @articol)``` " .In this case I can't make difference between two cases.I want to have all ItemId in case @Articole = -1 ,or filtered ItemId with @Articoel value (<>-1). I try with ```##``` but a get identic error message.

Answer (score 0):

We can create temporary table in two scopes,

1. Local Scope - created by declaring with '#' e.g `#Articole`
2. Global Scope - created by declaring with '##' e.g `##Articole`

Either create you temp Table outside the local scope or create it as globally.